# Is there a way to change a background-image without live-reloading?

Tags: css, angular

I'm actually trying to make an Angular pick&ban overlay for League of Legends tournaments, but I'm facing some fundamental issues and I'm not sure if it can even be done. My problem is : can I dynamically change a div background without reloading my component ?

In pick-ban-component.html :

```html
<div class="blueTeam">
   <app-player-card *ngFor="let player of blueTeam" [bluePlayer]="player"></app-player-card>
</div>
```

In pick-ban-component.ts :

```
public blueTeam = [{
        name: 'playerOne',
        champion: 'Teemo',
        spells: ['Flash', 'Burn']
    },...
];
```

In player-card.html :

```html
<div [ngClass]="bluePlayer ? 'bluePlayerCard bluePlayer.champion' : redPlayer ? 'redPlayerCard redPlayer.champion' : 'noSelection'"></div>
```

In player-card.css :

```css
.Teemo {
    background-image: url('../../assets/champions/Teemo_0.jpg') !important;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
}...
```

My player-card.css has every single champion registered the same way as Teemo is. So I would like to know if there is a way to avoid component reloading if I change the champion of playerOne to another one, but still provide a background change ?

Comment: Can you provide a stackbiltz

Comment: *can I dynamically change a div background without reloading my component ?* -- Yes you can. What is `bluePlayer` in `player-card.html`?

Comment: I did not used StackBlitz but I can share my GitHub repo : https://github.com/CyprienDeRoef/LoL-Overlay

I initiate player-card.ts with two empty variables : 
@Input() bluePlayer;
@Input() redPlayer;
so I can changes classes and css depending on team color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the simplest solution is to change this line:

```
<div [ngClass]="bluePlayer ? 'bluePlayerCard bluePlayer.champion' : redPlayer ? 'redPlayerCard redPlayer.champion' : 'noSelection'"></div>
```

to this:

```
<div [ngClass]="bluePlayer ? 'bluePlayerCard ' + bluePlayer.champion : redPlayer ? 'redPlayerCard ' + redPlayer.champion : 'noSelection'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngStyle

```
<div class='Teemo' [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + myBackground + ')' }"></div>
```